# Определение схожести слов

Tags: php

Есть слово, например "hello" (латиница), и второе слово - "hеllo" (буква "е" - на кириллице).
Необходимо сравнивать два слова и отдавать false , если слово похоже.

Нашёл решение на примере сравнения двух логинов: [источник](http://htmlweb.ru/php/example/proverka_pohojesti_slov.php)

Который прекрасно работает, если работать с cp1251.

Никак не могу понять: в какую сторону изменять скрипт, что бы работал с utf-8 ?

Меняю входные данные с UTF в cp1251 с помощью iconv - не спасает.

Какие варианты могут быть для изменения указанного скрипта под utf ?

Comment: попробуйте просто добавить флаг /u. Он позволит работать с кириллицей корректно.

Comment: Можно создать массив схожих букв и написать метод, который будет принимать оба слова, и сравнивать эти слова на предмет схожести из этого массива.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Флаг `u` для регекспов
2. Все строковые функции заменить на `mb_*` аналоги (может быть придётся вспомнить про доп. аргументы: `mb_strpos($pattern1,$letter,0,'utf-8')`

Всё, мне этого хватило, примеры проходят как там написано.

Comment: Да, эти два пункта решают вопрос, если исходное слово - полностью на латинице:) Если исходное слово, например "привет", то проверка слова "привет" в котором "e" - латинская - не работает уже.:)

Answer (score 1):

> Меняю входные данные с UTF в cp1251 с помощью iconv - не спасает.

Не надо так делать. Там не только кириллица может быть.

А вообще, я бы прям нарисовал картинку и сравнил попиксельно. Не думаю, что регистрация происходит достаточно часто, чтобы это вызвало излишнюю нагрузку.

Comment: На самом деле проверка в моём случае - идёт достаточно часто. Полагаю мне будет проще всё остальное под 1251 переписать:)

Comment: Плюсанул за "не надо так делать", но с изображением - еще более не надо так делать. Там должен быть еще более сложный алгоритм распознования схожести.

Comment: @Etki Ну, похожесть же надо исключить для того, чтобы на форуме один пользователь не маскировался под другого. Конечно, можно перебрать все возможные похожие символы, но для юникода это как-то сомнительно. Во-первых, их будет много, во-вторых, что если я запихаю невидимый пробел или пару символов, меняющих направление текста? Вариант с картинкой логичен в том плане, что он такой же, как восприятие текста человеком и не требует излишних усилий на реализацию. Но если нагрузка на сервер существенна, то действительно стоит поискать другие варианты.

Comment: Да при чем тут нагрузка на сервер. Это сломается на первом же символе, который чуть жирнее, чем его аналог из соседнего языка. Насколько знаю, в юникоде нет понятия "алиас" (несмотря на то, что некоторые символы используются для нескольких языков сразу), и никто не гарантирует нахождение в шрифте нужного символа или его идентичность.

Comment: @Etki, z не имел в виду полное совпадение картинок - что-то типа отклонение не более 10%. Нужное значение подбирается экспериментально. Что касается отсутствия символа в шрифте - ведь у пользователя при том же шрифте этот символ будет так же отсутствовать, так что это скорее плюс, чем минус: символы совсем разные, но оба заведомо отсутствуют в шрифте - это же выглядит одинаково, а не по-разному.

Comment: Разница между "∊трампампам" и "Єтрампампам" порядка ста процентов, потому что первый символ различной ширины.

Comment: @Etki, сравнивать покомпонентно, а не целиком. Ладно, ок, убедил :)

Comment: Сравнение "вообще всего" - это конечно тяжко. В данном случае и примере - изначально отрезается всё, что не аБaZ09. И, в принципе, вариант с /u вроде как правильное направление, но почему скрипт начинает ломаться в других местах - пока не вкурил. Сижу вкуриваю:)

Answer (score 1):

Общий ответ на этот вопрос - эта задача не решается приемлимыми времязатратами вообще. В мире и юникоде существует огромное количество символов, похожих друг на друга визуально, но при этом визуальную похожесть обеспечивает исключительно шрифт. В самом юникоде никаких данных о сходстве символов не содержится, пока два символа из разных языков не указывают на один и тот же идентификатор глифа.

Промежуточное решение, включающее только кириллицу и латиницу, подразумевает построение эша взаимозаменяемых символов, и, соответственно, преобразование двух сравниваемых версий текста в латиницу или кириллицу перед сравнением. Однако это, опять же, будет давать только ответ на вопрос "идентичны ли представления текстов" (т.е. нельзя отследить, выпала всего одна буква или весь текст) и потребует знатного тестирвоания перед выпуском в продакшен. Возможно, вам пригодятся функции типа [`levenshtein`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.levenshtein.php), [`similar_text`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.similar-text.php), хотя напрямую они задачу не решают, и, насколько понимаю, натыкаются на ту же юникодную проблему с неидентичностью кодов глифов.

Отдельным вопросом стоит вообще необходимость этого сравнения. Пока у вас не свежий поисковик, скорее всего, это решение вам вообще не нужно.

[Схожий вопрос на исходном so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260890/visually-identical-characters-in-unicode).